# What happens when the thread that is responsible for processing messages is hung?

Tags: winapi, window, message-queue, hwnd

I have an application in which one of the dll modules is responsible for processing user defined messages that get posted to its hidden window. Supposing the thread that is responsible to process these messages is hung while processing some other task and, during this time, if messages are posted (using `PostMessage`) by another low level layer to this window, what will happen to the posted messages?

My application sometimes does not receive those messages and the logs in the low level layer indicates that they have posted the message but my application did not receive it. I suspect that since the thread was busy or hung it would have not processed those messages. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: They get added to the message queue, you'll get them later whenever you stop being hung.  This is a finite resource, the default quota on the queue size is 10,000 messages.  The code that calls PostMessage() gets a FALSE return when the queue is full.  Nobody ever checks that.

Comment: If the thread that owns the window is blocked/hung, it is not retrieving and dispatching new messages from its message queue, so new messages will simply stay in the queue, and eventually the queue will fill up. So don't hang the thread to begin with.  If you need to perform a lengthy operation, move it to its own thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, that if you're using a hidden window to process messages both from the system and from your other application components, then it's important to keep that message pump running and processing messages. If you have a long running task that's going to keep you away from your message queue for an extended period of time then the correct answer is to pass off that task to a separate thread.

The more complicated answer is that there are probably two issues happening:

1. The message queue is full.
2. The return value from the call to `PostMessage` is not being checked properly.

The first issue is quite simple. The documentation for [`PostMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644944.aspx) is quite clear<sup>1</sup>:

> There is a limit of 10,000 posted messages per message queue. This limit should be sufficiently large. If your application exceeds the limit, it should be redesigned to avoid consuming so many system resources.

The take-home message is, a thread involved in message processing should do as little as absolutely necessary between trips to fetch the next message to keep the application responsive, and keep it from wasting resources.

The second issue, which may or may not exist in your code, is that the return from `PostMessage` needs to be checked. The documentation spells it out, but TL;DR; if the return value is 0, then the call failed.  If **and only if**<sup>2</sup> the return value was 0, call `GetLastError` to get the error code.  If the error is `ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA` then the queue is full. In snippet form:

```
if (PostMessage(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam) == 0)
{
    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_QUOTA)
    {
        cout << "Message Queue is Full" << endl;
    }
}
```

---

*<sup>1</sup> Usually MSDN isn't so forceful when saying that something shouldn't be done.  When it is so explicit about something, it's probably best to follow the advice.  (Also worth mentioning: increasing the quota would be a global solution to a local problem.)*

*<sup>2</sup> It's a shockingly common mistake to call `GetLastError` when a function succeeds, or when the function being called doesn't `SetLastError`.*